# CodeIgniter 3.0.6 and WireDesignz HMVC - Call to a member function on null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I have CodeIgniter 3.0.6 running with WireDesignz HMVC.

When running

```
modules::load('page/com_Page')->_GetPage();
```

I get online a

```
Call to a member function _GetPage() on null
```

But locally it is working.
The directory structure is as following

```
application
public_html
public_html/components
public_html/components/page
public_html/components/page/controllers/com_Page
system
```

in the config I have

```
$document_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$document_root_exploded = explode('/', $document_root);
$document_root_name = end($document_root_exploded); 

$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH . '../' . $document_root_name . '/components/' => '../../' . $document_root_name . '/components/',
);
```

I have no clue why local (Windows Apache) its working and online not (Linux).

Comment: "Class names must start with an uppercase letter." from the tutorial - maybe thats the problem

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Because I am also getting the same issue here: https://www.blognow.org/home I don't know what is causing it, its working fine on localhost. Just not working on Shared hosting

Comment: @harshallonare: Please see the solution below. Controllers has to start with a capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with case sensitive.
In HMVC the controllers have to start with a capital.